# Не отправляются данные Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel5

Отправлялись данные из формы на сервер с помощью php и добавлялись в бд, после того как попытался отправить данные через Ajax, они не приходят на сервер, хотя сам ajax запрос проходит. Где промах?

[image]

Comment: А вы как на сервере эти данные принимаете?

Comment: Вставьте код текстом

Comment: это что: `this.methodName`, `this.url`?

Answer (score 0):

что приходит в ответе? csrf-token передается?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

если нет, то в форме необходимо добавить {{ csrf_field() }}

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-introduction

или сделать вывод в head сайта мета тега, содержащего csrf_token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}>
```

и перед отправкой добавлять в header X-CSRF-TOKEN в запрос

```
var token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
...
header['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content
```

Comment: ответ доработан